# Multiplication modulo 10 in Cayley's Table

Tags: group-theory

[image]

In the Fourth row and second column, we have $3\cdot7 = 21$
But $9$ is the "limit", and note that there are $4$ elements in $U(10)$

Using modular arithmetic, $21= (4*5)+1$
Thus, $21 = 1 \pmod 4$

There ought to be $1$ instead of $7$ but the table implies otherwise. I'm pretty lost.

Comment: Why are you doing mod $4$ when this is mod $10$?

Comment: There IS a 1 in the fourth row second column.

Comment: $3\cdot7=2\cdot10+1=1\bmod 10$. What do you mean by "9 is the limit"?

Comment: I'm quite plausibly interpreting the idea of the Cayley's table wrongly after looking at your replies.
I took mod (4) because U(10) = {1,3,7,9} hence 4 integers.

Comment: You are. This is the table of the multiplication between invertible integers mod 10

Comment: I see what went wrong. Indeed, I have interpreted the table wrong. I know what went wrong now.

Comment: In a few minutes you can answer your own question (unless @AndreaMori does so first) so it won't remain on the unanswered list.

Comment: I would like to go on a tangent and ask the definition of 'order' in this context. Reading through my text, it mentioned that u(10) has order 4 and u(8) has order 3. What does this 'order' means?

Comment: *Order* is simply the number of elements, so in this case, 4.

Answer (score 2):

For any $N$, the symbol $U(N)$ denotes the [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29) of the integers invertible $\bmod N$ (or what amounts to say the integers having GCD $1$ with $N$) under multiplication.

Its order, i.e. the number of its elements, is $\varphi(N)$ where $\varphi$ denotes [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

As $U(N)$ is a group, general basic results of group theory imply that if ${\rm GCD}(a,N)=1$ then
$$
a^{\varphi(N)}\equiv1\bmod N.
$$
When $N=p$ is a prime number one has $\varphi(p)=p-1$, so this fact generalizes Fermat's Little Theorem.

Moreover, again when $N=p$ is prime, it can be proved that $U(p)$ is *cyclic*, i.e. there exists a class $\bar a\in U(p)$ (called a *generator*) such that any other class $\bar b$ is of the form $\bar b=\bar a^k$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. In fact, there exist always $\varphi(p-1)$ such generators in $U(p)$.

The ciclicity of $U(N)$ holds also for some composite $N$, but it is false in general: for instance $U(8)$ is not cyclic as $1^2\equiv3^2\equiv5^2\equiv7^2\equiv1\bmod8$ (thus, it is not possible to obtain $\bar 5$ taking powers of $\bar 3$ and so on)